# RoR Tutorial Michael Hartl 5.27

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm following the tutorial on Ruby on Rails from Michael Hartl and i'm having some trouble regarding the [third exercise of chapter 5](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-layout_exercises). I've created the application_helper_spec.rb with the exact code as the one in the book and the utilities.rb now just have the line indicated in [listing 5.38](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#code-rspec_utilities_simplified), but when I run the test suite I get this error:

```
C:.../sample_app/spec/helpers/appliaction_helper_spec.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
desc...ApplicationHelper do
```

The first line of the file is: `require 'spec_helper'`, and when I delete this line, I don't get this error, but I really don't think that's the right solution.

Here's the code from the file (same as the book's)

```
require 'spec_helper'

  describe ApplicationHelper do

    describe "full_title" do
      it "should include the page title" do
        full_title("foo").should =~ /foo/
      end

      it "should include the base title" do
        full_title("foo").should =~ /^Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App/
      end

      it "should not include a bar for the home page" do
        full_title("").should_not =~ /\|/
      end
    end
  end
```

[edit] spec_helper:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

[edit] application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  #Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What does your spec_helper look like?

Comment: try unindent `describe Application do ... end` block

Comment: please show you application_helper.rb

Comment: are you had `include ApplicationHelper` in utilities.rb?

Comment: There is no syntax error on line one of the file you posted, so either you made an error copying the error message (which you admit is true) or you made an error in copying application_helper_spec.rb.  You should edit your post carefully and use the Copy and Paste feature of your OS to make sure we can see exactly what is on your screen for both the error message and the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on filename:

```
appliaction_helper_spec.rb => application_helper_spec.rb
```

Comment: actually, it was my mistake when typing the error message, the filename is correct

Comment: oh, so you should check again code, maybe you miss something.